# Cheerio - how to get full recursive html of a selector that returns multiple items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, cheerio

If one does

```
//=>  <ul id="fruits">
//      <li class="apple">Apple</li>
//      <li class="plum">Plum</li>
//      <li class="apple">Apple TOoo</li>
//      <li class="pear">Pear</li>
//    </ul>
$('.apple').html();
```

it will output only

```
 <li class="apple">Apple TOoo</li>
```

but, I want to get the html of all the elements returned combined, currently it only returns the first, as according to the docs: `Gets an HTML content string from the first selected element.` https://cheerio.js.org/classes/Cheerio.html#html

How do I do this with Cheerio?
If I use the top level .html(node) with a specific node, then if it has subchildren, they render as `Object[Object]`.

But, `.text()` traverses the whole list of results and combines them. `text()` doesn't look at the first element only.  What is the equivalent for `.html()`?  Alternatively, I don't mind combining the string results of multiple `html()` calls, but then the children being rendered as literal Object strings messes up the whole thing.

Comment: Given that there's no HTML within the `.apple` elements, can you not just us `text()` anyway? Assuming this is just a contrived example, you could use `map()` to build an array from the HTML within that collection of elements and `join()` it together. The best approach would depend on your exact use case.

Comment: if you dont mind combining results, then you might use cheerios `each` as in  `$('.apple').each( el => el.html() ).join("\n")`

Comment: oops, mixed up things, better try `map` as in  `$('.apple').map( (i, el) => $(el).html() ).get().join("\n")`

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could have just been using `Cheerio.load(..)` to load the html instead of trying to render it from each node itself.

```
let nodes = Cheerio.load(theHtmlBody)('.apple');

return nodes.map( (i, el) => Cheerio.load(el).html() ).get().join("\n");
```

<sub>Thanks to @PA.'s comments above</sub>